# Android EditText, select all horizontally scrolls to end of text. Want it to scroll back to the beginning of the text

Tags: android, android-edittext, selectall

I am using an EditText to display a large amount of text in an area that is smaller than the length of the text. 
If I use the EditText.selectAll() or EdiTtext.setSelectAllOnFocus(true) the text is automatically scrolled to the end, so only the end of the text is visible.
I would like to find a way to make sure the beginning of the text is visible after it is selected.

Example "1234567890ABCDEF" in a EditText that is only wide enough to show 6 characters, so normally only 123456 would be visible. If the text is selected then ABCDEF is visible. I would like to have the text selected (highlighted), but display 123456.